# How to download datapump from AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

Some time ago AWS implemented datapump on RDS servers.

Amont other things, it allows me to create a dump file that I want to download to provide to my client as a end of service artifact.

How can I download these datapump file ? Can I do an SCP from my EC2 instance ? What is the path to download ? Something like :/rdsdbdata/datapump/myfile ?

Comment: Did you try the steps in this documentation page? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Yes I did. There's only instructions to import, not for export. I tried to use exp with some success, but my network break after some hours of export. The database is not so huge, but my network is far away from my RDS instance, and in the first chance the connection broke.